# Installing a local repo in RHEL

Tags: redhat, yum

i found that error during my installation of a local repo in RHEL pay attention that cdrom's contents don't have neither BaseOS , AppStream nor Package directories which should be mounted under it so what should i do ? , every time i install a package like `system-config-kickstart` as an example an err appears :

> Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'Rhel.8.0_BaseOS':   - Curl error (37): Couldn't read a file:// file
> for file:///rhel.8_dvd/BaseOS/repodata/repomd.xml [Couldn't open file
> /rhel.8_dvd/BaseOS/repodata/repomd.xml] Error: Failed to download
> metadata for repo 'Rhel.8.0_BaseOS': Cannot download repomd.xml:
> Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

Comment: where is mounted your CD?

Answer (score 0):

you can mount your rhel iso and create a local repo

```
mount /xxxx.iso /media
```

this is a basic repo configuration

```
[media.repo]
baseurl=file:///media
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
name=xxx
```

after refreshing repolist this should work with you